# Install app to user profile

Tags: facebook, web-applications, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps

I have an application in facebook. And I want to add the ability for installing this app on the user's personal timeline.
What is to be done in the application?

I tried to found any answer in the documentation (for example  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/ ). I found a way to install an app to the fan page only.
But I need the ability to install app to the user's personal profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Tabs" (in the way you can build them for pages) are not supported on user-profiles since more than 2 years!

The only way to have an application-tile on a users profile (like shown on the screenshot below) is by publishing Open Graph-actions through the app.

[image]

However, these are not "Tabs" in the sense that you have an iframe which you can build to your needs. They simply display the Open Grap-aggregations defined in the app-dashboard:

[image]

Also, these Timeline-aggregations seem to be quite buggy since quite a while, so I wouldn't recommend relying to much on them:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/434970296563783